# Null pointer while Injecting Logger object Using DI in Spring 3.1.0

Tags: spring, web-applications, dependency-injection, log4j, slf4j

i intend to use logger(log4J with slf4j) with Spring DI.

I am trying to initialise the main logger class using DI and autowiring that instance in a test class.
But that instance is always coming null. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.
Please note its a web application deployed on IBM WAS 6.1.

Here is what i am doing

All classes are inside **com.test** package.

```
@Repository
           public class TestLogger
            {

            @Autowired
            MainLogger error; // this instance of Mainlogger is always null         

    //if **MainLogger error = new MainLogger();**  is used this is working fine!!
           public void test(){

             error.logerror("test"); //null pointer here

             }
           }
```

MainLogger Class

```
public class MainLogger {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainLogger.class);
         String str = "Logger check check";
        logger.info(str); 

    }
        public void loginfo(String para)
        {
             Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VpayCoreLogger.class);
             logger.info(para);
        }

        public void logdebug(String para)
        {
            Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VpayCoreLogger.class);
            logger.debug(para);
        }

        public void logerror(String para)
        {
            Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VpayCoreLogger.class);

            logger.error(para);
        }

    }

}
```

Application Context XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

<bean id="error" class="com.test.MainLogger">
</bean>


<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>

</beans>
```

WEB XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>testApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>testDAO.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well not sure if its the answer but i got it to work somehow.
The catch was to either Autowire the field using setter or Constructor.

```
@Repository
public class TestLogger
{

private static MainLogger error;     
@Autowired
public TestLogger(MainLogger error)
{
 this.error=error;
}

public TestLogger()
{

}
 public void test(){

       error.logerror("test");     
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate `TestLogger` with `@Component` to make it a bean.  Otherwise it will not get picked up by the component scan, making it ineligible for autowiring/DI.

```
   @Component
   public class TestLogger
   {
      //code goes here
   }
```

Comment: Its still cooming as null, i forgot to add that i have already used @Repository over the TestLogger

Comment: Are you bootstrapping the application context in web.xml? Please post.

Comment: yes , i am loading the application context in web xml. Updated the code for webxml.

Comment: Which method are you using for testing and in what class?  If your using a constructor to initialize your test class DI will fail.  The class harness itself must be part of the DI container.

Comment: Well, im just using a JSP to in which im calling the TestLogger Class. new TestLogger().test(); .What I am doing wrong? I thought that when my server publishes the web app it loads and inject all the beans? if not how does this actually work. or how can i test my logger using DI?